# VS Code highlight modified lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am unable to find a setting to enable modified/changed/new lines highlight in editor. Like on this screenshot from the video about angular2 by google.

How to enable modified line hilight?

[image: Vs code modified/changed/new lines highlight]

Comment: We really need it! There is a request in its Github, perhaps you could vote for it too!

Comment: In March 11th, 2023 a new version (1.76) was released and it messed up with the highlighting modified lines features in Windows. I just published an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176851). If you want a quick fix, downgrade to 1.75

Comment: you can do it by adding your repository in the source control

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is connected with your file being under revision control. If you have your files in `git` and open the folder in VS Code. You will see the colors depending on the change you've made.

[image]

Check section about [Gutter indicators](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_gutter-indicators).

Comment: You are right about gutter indicators, thanks. Seens that change tracking like in VS 2015 is not possible in VS Code. I have googled a lot but failed to find anything about it.

Comment: In my case, the file which is missing the highlight is currently staged on git. Unstaging the file from git, VS Code will highlight the changed lines.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem try launching vscode in terminal like: `code your-project-dictionary`.
If code command cannot be found, enable code in shell:
Open VSCode press `CMD`+`Shift`+`P`. A dialog will be shown: Type in "shell" and click on `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`. Now you can launch VSCode in terminal. This solved my issue with highlighting changed files on VSC Project Structure!

Comment: looks like file explorer indicates edited, new files 
and in editor - new, modified, removed lines 
are indicated only if I start VS Code from terminal

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and turns out that for me it was a bug in git client. Reinstalling git resolved the problem with changes highlighting. Ensure that you are using latest git client. Then reopen VSCode, reopen project/folder.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should open with folder, rather than open just files.

open just files:
[img example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEzFT.png)

open with folder:
[img example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqc4x.png)

anyway, in terminal, use `code xxxx(folder name)` to open project, or right click the floder and choose open with vscode in context

Answer (score 1):

> **Tip: must open the real directory, but not a link dir**

if you add fold to a workspace, also must add a real direcotory

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "../src/xxx/"
        },
        {   # ../golang/src/test must be a real dir
            "path": "../golang/src/test" 

        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used a theme that, for some reason, hid these indicators, so I needed to explicitly specify the colors I want to use in my settings.json:

```json
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGutter.addedBackground": "#28a745", // Color for added lines (green)
    "editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#2188ff", // Color for modified lines (blue)
    "editorGutter.deletedBackground": "#cb2431", // Color for removed lines (red)
    "diffEditor.insertedTextBackground": "#28a74533", // Background color for added text (green with transparency)
    "diffEditor.removedTextBackground": "#cb243133", // Background color for removed text (red with transparency)
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a folder open in your VSCode explorer for this to work and give it full access. I recommend opening your base/root folder so it works for all of your repos:

1. Click the folder file icon in the top left
2. 'Open Folder' > choose your base folder
3. When asked, give full permissions